# Migrating users from DotNetNuke to Orchard CMS

Tags: dotnetnuke, orchardcms

I have an existing site built on DotNetNuke, but we are considering a migration to Orchard CMS. I would like to avoid requiring our users to re-register on the new Orchard site, but have not been able to find any tools or information for migrating users. My biggest concern is dealing with hashed passwords.

Does anyone have experience migrating users between these two CMSs?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the password encryption that was used.  Some encryption types can be decrypted and some cannot.

I wrote a DNN module that would could decrypt passwords because the company wanted to set up users on another website.  They wanted to use the same username/password and make it transparent for the employees.  You could modify this to just write all the usernames/passwords to a database table or file.

It was based off code like this: [DNN Decrypting Password](http://aquamoonblog.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/decrypting-a-dotnetnuke-password-c/) or [Another SqlMembership Decryption article](http://www.waynester.net/blog/archive/2011/09/12/dotnetnuke-password-decrypting-with-code.aspx)

You could also buy a module off the DNN store to export users: [Bulk User Export](http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/bulk-user-import-export-365-standart-edition)

But, none of these methods will work if your site is using a one-way hashing algorithm.  The only thing you can do if that is the case is import the users with a set password.

After you get the users exported, you just have to import them into Orchard via some importing tool like: [Orchard Import](https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Webstation.Module.UserImport)